# How to Create an SQL Server Instance on SQL Server Management Studio 2017 (SSMS v17.0)

Tags: ssms

How do I go about creating a new Local SQL Server Instance for SQL Server Management Studio 2017.

In previous version I have installed it was part of the installation process, but it was removed for some reason. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since SQL 2016, the database engine and the management tools (SSMS/profiler/etc.) [come in separate downloads and are upgraded separately](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143601/was-management-studio-removed-from-sql-server-2016-installation-media).

Since you already have SSMS, you need to download the DB engine, which can be downloaded from here (SQL Server 2017 currently): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads